# Scanning rownames in HBase without any column data

Tags: java, hbase

How can I scan through rownames in HBase without requesting any column data? 
I want to make the scan faster by omitting all columns as I need just the rownames.

EDIT:
Ok figured it out myself...to get only the rownames [FistKeyOnlyFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FirstKeyOnlyFilter.html) can be used. This filter does return more than just the rowkeys but only the first key values from each row so it is much more efficient than requesting the whole row... 
If anyone has a better idea, I'm still open for a better way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right filter. If you wanted to improve further this behavior, you could write your own filter and add it to HBase classpath and your client classpath. As part of the filters coming from HBase, this is the only one I can see in 0.92 that serves you the best.